# Error while adding remote Git repository in Review Board

Tags: git, ssh, review-board

I am trying to setup Review Board (1.7.13). I want to add a Git repository which resides on a remote machine. I went to *Manage* -> *Repositories* -> *Add* and did the following steps:

1. Added `Name`.
2. Selected *Hosting service* as `None`.
3. Selected *Repository type* as `Git`.
4. Chose *Path* as `username@10.10.94.4:/localhome/gitusers/username/reponame.git`.
5. Left *Mirror Path* and *Raw file URL mask* empty.
6. Entered *Username* and *Password*.

After saving, I get the following error:

> A repository was not found at the specified path.

I looked at the logs, it shows as:

> 2013-08-27 14:07:18,035 - INFO -  - Authentication (publickey) failed.
>   2013-08-27 14:07:18,046 - DEBUG -  - userauth is OK
>   2013-08-27 14:07:23,062 - INFO -  - Authentication (password) successful!
>   2013-08-27 14:07:23,161 - DEBUG -  - EOF in transport thread
>   2013-08-27 14:07:23,187 - ERROR -  - Git: Failed to find valid repository ssh://username@10.10.94.4/localhome/gitusers/username/reponame.git: error: cannot spawn rbssh: No such file or directory
>   fatal: unable to fork

I noticed in the log above that the `:` behind the IP address is no longer there (See ERROR line). How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this working. In addition to what you did, I also enabled ssh keys between review board and git. To do this I did the following:

- in the review board admin "system setting / ssh" admin screen, Generate a key, then set that key in .ssh/authorized_keys on the git server.
- I also manually created a key (as root) on the git server (with ssh-keygen) and add that key to .ssh/authorized_keys on the git server.

I also set the raw file url mask to:

```
http://[ipaddr]/cgi-bin/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=reponame.git;a=blob_plain;f=<filename>;h=<revision>
```

If that doesn't work, you'll probably have better luck asking on the review board support forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/reviewboard) some of the maintainers seems to reply to problems there regularly.

Comment: if I dont want to install gitweb, is there an alternate method?

Comment: I don't think so, I think you need gitweb installed.

Comment: I got gitweb installed. What path did you provide (I cant skip as its a mandatory field)? I inserted the raw file url mask as you mentioned but still does not work due to wrong path. Note, I can access git tree through browser using gitweb url: http://[ipaddress]/?p=reponame.git;a=summary